# How to securely trigger Jenkins builds from GitHub

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins instance running behind a firewall, and I do not want to expose the Jenkins UI to the Internet. (Even with security on, that is definitely not an option).

My wish would be to open a different port, that is only able to trigger builds, but does not expose the UI. I browsed the plugin list, but I did not find any suitable plugin.

My current setup is running Apache as a proxy and allowing the trigger via regex-module on a different port. (But not any other URL.)

Apache does too much extra load (and memory; it's a very small machine), so I would really like to get rid of it.

How do I allow triggers via an open port, but not exposing the Jenkins UI or other Jenkins URLs through that port?

Comment: @Andrew There are multiple reasons why I consider polling not as an option. [This](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/) is one.

Comment: Agreed, GitHooks are nice but in many corporate environments, setting up GitHooks is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have a setup that meets my requirements: low resource usage and secure. I replaced Apache by a small Bash script using `net cat` to emulate a web server:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do
   echo -e "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r" | nc -l -v -p [outer port number] > /dev/null
   wget -O /dev/null [jenkins base url]/git/notifyCommit?url=[repository url] &>/dev/null
   sleep 5
done
```

- The first line (in the loop) responses with HTTP no content status which is supported by the GitHub trigger. The payload is directed to `/dev/null`. It's important to not look at the payload and try to extract details in the shell script, because sanitizing input is easily done wrong in Bash (at least for me).
- The second line triggers Jenkins to look for changes (and the build if there are changes).
- The sleep in the last line is to prevent a [DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) scenario if the listening port would be invoked too often.
- The script itself is started via cron with a `@reboot`schedule.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to turn the problem around you could poll the GitHub repository for changes. The polling schedule can be configured with [crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) syntax.

"5 asterisks" in crontab means poll every minute of every hour of every day. More or less the same as every building every commit.